# Win11: Screensaver: Randomize photos...is not random

Tags: windows, screensaver

I have the settings shown below.

But the pictures are always shown... in the same order.... Same 1st pic, same 2nd pic.

It is like it shuffled once, and preserves that forever after....

How to make it actually random?

Win10 had the same behavior.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if its possible, but one thing I'm curious about, if you uncheck the random setting, is the sequence different, and if you check it again, does it return to the first sequence, or does it generate a new sequence very time the setting is toggled off and then on?

Comment: @LPChip So unchecking it did change the sequence, and rechecking it seems to have put the old "shuffle" sequence back (not %100, but think so). Oddly, in ALL cases, the first jpg shown is _always_ the same.

Comment: Try in *Settings > Accounts > Sync your settings*, to uncheck "Other Windows settings", or just to temporarily disable syncing entirely.

Comment: Not sure you can solve this bug, but one thing you can do is search for a different screensaver that does work. Screensavers are just renamed .exe files with an interface to work as screensavers. I'm sure there are better alternatives out there, possibly even free.